# How to call JSP within a folder from servlet that is also within a folder

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a project in Netbeans. In "Source Packages" I have a servlet, myServlet.java. But it is inside folders. Its com.login.controller. In "Web Pages" I have 2 JSPs, `login.jsp` and `home.jsp`. `login.jsp` is inside of folder `"jsp/login/login.jsp"` while home.jsp is at `"jsp/home/home.jsp".`

Now my question is what is the best way of invoking JSP page from servlet when using getRequestDispatcher? In my login.jsp when I clicked login button it call myServlet.java and then it will process if the inputs are valid it should then directed in home.jsp using getRequestDispatcher. What Should I enter in its parameter as path? What I thought are the ff:

```
getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
getRequestDispatcher("jsp/home/home.jsp");
getRequestDispatcher("../../../jsp/home/home.jsp"); //Getting back of
```

directory 3x because I thought my servlet is inside 3 folders that's why.

But all of these 3 did not work. What should I do? I don't know. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thing you have to use 'getRequestDispatcher("home/home.jsp")', this should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of contextpath, it will give you root path.

```
request.getContextPath()
```

So if you want to access home.jsp, navigate from Web-Content folder i.e

```
getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()+"/jsp/home/home.jsp");
```

Similarly, when you want to send request to Servlet, you can use

```
 getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()+"/myServlet.java");
```